# ListActivity with no view/layout produces (ERROR) ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, logcat

I created a new project in Android Studio, a listactivity, it has no view/layout (xml) associated and I am using the built in row "simple_list_item_1" with it (built in Android layout). It seems to work but I see the following in the LogCat

```
 "ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView"
```

Here is part of the logcat message:

```
  06-13 01:42:49.911    1711-1711/com.commonsware.myapplication4.app 
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.commonsware.myapplication4.app, PID: 1711
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

                at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
```

And here is my simple activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
            "sit", "amet",
            "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel",
            "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis",
            "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
            "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items));
    }
}
```

It is perfectly legal to create a listactivity without a xml layout as Android is supposed to create its own, and it appears to be doing that as the list is rendered with all my items but the error appears in the logcat which is concerning.

Is this a bug? accepted problem?

I did create this application from the beginning and it has minimal code but enough for it to work, and appears to be working, apart from the error message in logcat.

Do I ignore it ? Is it a bug ? Am I doing something wrong?

***EDIT - No Layout needed for ListActivity***

It states here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listactivity_overview

> You do not have to assign a layout to these elements. If you do not define a layout, the activity or fragment contains a single ListView by default. ListActivity and ListFragment also allow you to override a onListItemClick() method for handling selection of list items.

***EDIT - Full Stack Trace of the error.***

```
06-13 01:42:49.771    1711-1711/com.commonsware.myapplication4.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-13 01:42:49.791    1711-1711/com.commonsware.myapplication4.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-13 01:42:49.871    1711-1711/com.commonsware.myapplication4.app E/ArrayAdapter﹕ You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
06-13 01:42:49.881    1711-1711/com.commonsware.myapplication4.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-13 01:42:49.881    1711-1711/com.commonsware.myapplication4.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a57ba8)
06-13 01:42:49.911    1711-1711/com.commonsware.myapplication4.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.commonsware.myapplication4.app, PID: 1711
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: try this way :  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,items);

Comment: android.R.i.text1 = cannot resolve symbol text1,  and logcat error still is printed out.

Comment: i have run your code but i not see error as you told can you please let me know which error log level have you find this error?

Comment: Hi Haresh, the cannot resolve symbol is displayed in the ide on editor and text1 is in red. My logcat is set to verbose.

Comment: I will update my question will a full stack trace.

Comment: I have set my compilesdk to v19 and myh min verison to 9 and my target verison to 19

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate(Bundle someBundle)` after calling to the super class `super.onCreate(someBundle);` you need to call to :

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

and create a main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

Notice the `android:id` is set to `@android:id/list` this is important for android to do the normal behavior for the ListActivity class

even though you are using a list activity every activity expects you to call

```
   setContentView(R.layout.some_layout_in_xml);
```

Comment: But a ListActivity can exist without a layout file i.e. R.layout.main, it is supposed to create it's own. This is what i understand from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

list_item.xml
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
</LinearLayout>


    private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
            "sit", "amet",
            "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel",
            "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis",
            "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
            "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.txtTitle,items));
    }
```

Comment: These do fix the issue, but this is providing a layout, and with ListActivity you don't have to provide a layout, a layout is provided for you if you inherit from ListActivity and no xml file is available...

Answer (score 0):

The error comes because the default layout **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1**. Try to create your own layout, for example: **my_simple_row_list.xml**

```
<TextView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

It worked for me, I hope it'll for you too.